# How to get mean value of heatmap inside bounding box area

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the mean value of the heatmap for the bounding box (the purple mask over the car) area of the image. Both objects are numpy arrays, but I am struggling to find a suitable function for calculating the mean heatmap value inside the mask.

[image]

I've appended a minimal working example that replicates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.zeros((10,10))
mask[3:-3, 3:-3] = 1 # white square in black background
im = mask + np.random.randn(10,10) # random image
masked = np.ma.masked_where(mask == 0, mask)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im, 'BuGn')
plt.imshow(masked, 'jet',  alpha=0.9)
plt.show()
```

where I would like to calculate the mean value of `im` inside the blue square (`masked`).

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try any of the methods from the  ```statistics``` module?

Comment: I guess something like this will do the job: ```mean = statistics.mean([statistics.mean([row for row in im]))```.

Comment: @accdias Thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking to find the mean value of `im` inside `masked`

Comment: You're welcome, @Sam Comber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Make mask of first 4 diagonal elements
h, w = 6, 10
mask = np.zeros((h,w),dtype=np.uint8)
mask[0][0] = 1
mask[1][1] = 1
mask[2][2] = 1
mask[3][3] = 1

# Make image of random small numbers under 10 that Mark is capable of adding up
# Go for predictable randomness because Mark is not a physicist
np.random.seed(42)
im = np.random.randint(1,10,(h,w),dtype=np.uint8)

# Calculate mean of numbers where mask>0
mean = im[mask>0].mean()
```

Here is how the mask looks:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here is how the image looks:

[image]

Here is the mean:

```
In [33]: mean                                                                                       
Out[33]: 5.75
```

**Check**:

```
(7 + 5 + 3 + 8) /4 = 23/4 = 5.75
```